# Use markup file inside assembly

Tags: c#

How i can open an xml or xsl file inside the same assembly from source code in C#?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google found this

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml;

class Application
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
       Stream s = 
          Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("File1.xml");

       XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();

       using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s))
           xdoc.LoadXml(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```